# Pull website's signing authority's certificate

Tags: certificates

There's a Docker registry running on my company's internal network at, say, registry.com.  I know that the registry is legit but when I run

```bash
docker login registry.com
```

it complains that the certificate is signed by an unknown authority.

Is there a way, from the command line, to download/construct the .crt file for the authority so that I can add it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and run `update-ca-certificates`?

I know I could add registry.com to `"insecure-registries"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` but I'd like a more general solution that isn't Docker-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example, `curl` but personally I find `openssl` easier to use. So here is an example on how to use `openssl` to achieve it.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername registry.com -connect registry.com:443 </dev/null
```

The `</dev/null` part is just so we get our terminal back.